# Not refreshing data each time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have weired problem in my project.I have 2 tabs and in one tab i have chekboxes and submit button and user will select from checkboxes and on button click he will get what he has selected from checkboxes in another tab.It runs perfectly.But sometimes it does not refresh the data from ajax ,jquery and i have to complete refresh my page.I am not able to identify the problem as i am not getting any error. Atleast i have to click for more than 15 times then it will not refresh the data otherwise it works fine.
Here is my js code:

```
function getFahrzeuge() { 
            var opts = [];
            $("#fahrzeuge input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
                {
                opts.push($(this).attr("id"));
                }

            }); 
            return opts;
        } 

        function saveFahrzeugeWidget(opts){

        if(opts.length == 0) return false;

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "ajax/dashboard.php",
          dataType : 'json',
          cache: false,
            data: {'filterOpts' :opts, 'aktion' : 'save-widget-vehicle'},
          success: function(data){
           //getFahrzeugeWidget();
             $('#fahrzeuge').html(data['html']); 

          },
          error: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
              }
        });
      }


      function getFahrzeugeWidget(opts){
        if(!opts || !opts.length){
          opts = allFahrzeuge;
        }

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "ajax/dashboard.php",
          dataType : 'json',
          cache: false,
          data: {filterOpts:opts, 'aktion' : 'get-widget-vehicle'},
          success: function(data){
            $('#fahrzeuge').html(data.html);
          },
          error: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
              }
        });
      }    

      function getFahrzeugeWidgetEdit(opts){
        if(!opts || !opts.length){
          opts = allFahrzeuge;
        }

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "ajax/dashboard.php",
          dataType : 'json',
          cache: false,
          data: {filterOpts:opts, 'aktion' : 'get-widget-vehicle-edit'},
          success: function(data){

             $('#fahrzeuge').html(data.html);
          },
          error: function(data){
                    alert('error' + data);
              }
        });
      }    

      $('#fahrzeuge .butt-rahmen').live('click', function(){
            var opts = getFahrzeuge();
            if($(this).attr('id') == 'saveId')
            {
                    saveFahrzeugeWidget(opts);   
                    if($('#fahrzeuge input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length <=0) {
                                alert('überprüfen Sie bitte atleast ein fahrzeuge');
                                //getFahrzeugeWidgetEdit(opts);
                         }                            
          }

            });
```

Comment: Append timestamp to your AJAX Url and it should work fine. Just append <<YOUR URL>> **&_<<Timestamp>>** and things will work as expected

Comment: i tried before that thing but still having the same problem...

Comment: Which browser are you using? Have you tried saveral browsers and still got the same caching issue?

Comment: i am using Firefox ...I will check now with the other browsers...but i think the problem is in my code somewhere...after atleast 15 click it fails to  refresh my data... :( its a minor problem somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is getting cached. And you are receiving the same answer. Try to add a new parameter to data as timestamp.

So your data should look like this.

```
data: {'filterOpts' :opts, 'aktion' : 'save-widget-vehicle', 'timestamp': new Date().getTime()},
```

Comment: even i thought previously i am sorry i tried but still getting the same thing...i dont understand sometimes on button click it will run fine but sometimes it does not refresh data and in firebug i can see it will pass the correct parameter